# Right Approach for a General Purpose Batching Class

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

I'm looking for a class that will allow me to add items to process and when the item count equals the batch size performs some operation. I would use it something like this:

```
   Batcher<Token> batcher = new Batcher<Token>(500, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)) {
      public void onFlush(List<Token> tokens) {
          rest.notifyBatch(tokens);
      }
   };

   tokens.forEach((t)->batcher.add(t));
   batcher.awaitDone();
```

After #awaitDone I know that all tokens have been notified. The #onFlush might do anything, for example, I might want to batch inserts into a database. I would like #onFlush invocations to be put into a Executor.

I came up with a solution for this but it seems like a lot of code, so my question is this, is there a better way I should be doing this? Is there an existing class other than the one I implemented or a better way to implement this? Seems like my solution has a lot of moving pieces.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
/**
 * Simple class to allow the batched processing of items and then to alternatively wait
 * for all batches to be completed.
 */
public abstract class Batcher<T> {

    private final int batchSize;
    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<T> batch;
    private final Executor executor;
    private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
    private final AtomicInteger processed = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public Batcher(int batchSize, Executor executor) {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.executor = executor;
        this.batch = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(batchSize);
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        processed.incrementAndGet();
        while (!batch.offer(item)) {
            flush();
        }
    }

    public void addAll(Iterable<T> items) {
        for (T item : items) {
            add(item);
        }
    }

    public int getProcessedCount() {
        return processed.get();
    }

    public void flush() {
        if (batch.isEmpty())
            return;

        final List<T> batched = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
        batch.drainTo(batched, batchSize);
        if (!batched.isEmpty())
            executor.execute(new PhasedRunnable(batched));
    }

    public abstract void onFlush(List<T> batch);

    public void awaitDone() {
        flush();
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
    }

    public void awaitDone(long duration, TimeUnit unit) throws TimeoutException {
        flush();
        try {
            phaser.awaitAdvanceInterruptibly(phaser.arrive(), duration, unit);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private class PhasedRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final List<T> batch;

        private PhasedRunnable(List<T> batch) {
            this.batch = batch;
            phaser.register();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                onFlush(batch);
            }
            finally {
                phaser.arrive();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A Java 8 solution would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s striking me is that your code doesn’t work with more than one thread adding items to a single `Batcher` instance. If we turn this limitation into the specified use case, there is no need to use specialized concurrent classes internally. So we can accumulate into an ordinary `ArrayList` and swap this list with a new one when the capacity is exhausted, without the need to copy items. This allows simplifying the code to

```
public class Batcher<T> implements Consumer<T> {

    private final int batchSize;
    private final Executor executor;
    private final Consumer<List<T>> actualAction;
    private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
    private ArrayList<T> batch;
    private int processed;

    public Batcher(int batchSize, Executor executor, Consumer<List<T>> c) {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.executor = executor;
        this.actualAction = c;
        this.batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
    }

    public void accept(T item) {
        processed++;
        if(batch.size()==batchSize) flush();
        batch.add(item);
    }

    public int getProcessedCount() {
        return processed;
    }

    public void flush() {
        List<T> current = batch;
        if (batch.isEmpty())
            return;
        batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
        phaser.register();
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                actualAction.accept(current);
            }
            finally {
                phaser.arrive();
            }
        });
    }

    public void awaitDone() {
        flush();
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
    }

    public void awaitDone(long duration, TimeUnit unit) throws TimeoutException {
        flush();
        try {
            phaser.awaitAdvanceInterruptibly(phaser.arrive(), duration, unit);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

regarding Java 8 specific improvements, it uses a `Consumer` which allows to specify the final action via lambda expression without the need to subclass `Batcher`. Further, the `PhasedRunnable` is replaced by a lambda expression. As another simplification, `Batcher<T> implements Consumer<T>` which elides the need for a method `addAll` as every `Iterable` supports `forEach(Consumer<? super T>)`.

So the use case now looks like:

```
Batcher<Token> batcher = new Batcher<>(
    500, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4), currTokens -> rest.notifyBatch(currTokens));

tokens.forEach(batcher);
batcher.awaitDone();
```

Comment: Thanks @Holger, why doesn't my code work if multiple threads are calling #add?

Comment: Because calling `add` followed by `awaitDone` matches the “check-then-act” pattern. It breaks if another thread performs an action (either `add` or `awaitDone`) in-between. Further, you have configured the `Phaser` with `1` which obviously implies that two threads calling `awaitDone` wouldn’t work.

Comment: So two threads can call #add but only one thread can call #awaitDone. That would allows multiple producers but only one #awaitDone. That's a limitation I can live with.